# Finding the generating function of the random variable given by $P(X=m)=\frac{1}{m(m+1)}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, generating-functions

Finding the generating function of the random variable given by $P(X=m)=\frac{1}{m(m+1)}$.

So I've tried using the definition:
$G_X(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s^nP(X=m)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s^n\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$, if it was only $\frac{s^n}{n}$ I could use the power series for log at 0. But, in this case I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the generating function for
\begin{align*}
G( s) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{s ^{n}}{n}
\end{align*}
you can apply the operator $\left[s ^{-1} \int_{}^{} \right]$ once to obtain
\begin{align*}
  \left[ \frac{1}{s} \int_{}^{} \right]G( s)
  =\frac{1}{s} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \int_{}^{} \frac{s ^{n}}{n}
  = \frac{1}{s} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{s ^{n+1}}{n ( n + 1)}
  = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{s^n}{n ( n + 1)}
.\end{align*}

> We have
> \begin{align*}
> G( s) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{s ^{n}}{n}
> =& \ln\!\left( \frac{1}{1 - s}\right) 
> \\
> \implies &\left[ \frac{1}{s}\int_{}^{} \right]\ln\!\left( \frac{1}{1 - s}\right) 
> = \frac{( s - 1)\ln\!\left( 1 - s\right) + s + c}{s}
> \end{align*}
> for some constant $c$.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the series expansion $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{s^n}{n} =-\log(1-s)$ twice by noting that

$$\frac 1{n(n+1)} = \frac 1n - \frac 1{n+1}$$

Hence,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{s^n}{n(n+1)} = -\log(1-s)-\frac 1s\left(-\log(1-s)-s\right)=\frac 1s(1-s)\log(1-s) + 1$$